# In React, how do I display the results from an API get request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I've created API's for a standard transaction application (using mongoDB for DB), I have API's for users, products and orders. I managed to use and display the information stored about users and products, however, when I try to follow the same code for displaying my orders (which shares objects from products and users, in mongoDB collections) I get stuck. I know this has something to do with how I've named (const { _id, username, useremail, productname, productsellprice } = order;) as the _id works.

Other details: using= axios for http requests; context api with hooks (useContext, useReducer)

Im new to all this so forgive me if I've left out crucial information.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import OrderContext from '../../context/order/orderContext';

    const OrderItem = ({ order }) => {
      const orderContext = useContext(OrderContext);
      const { deleteOrder, setCurrent, clearCurrent } = orderContext;

      const { _id, username, useremail, productname, productsellprice } = order;

      const onDelete = () => {
        deleteOrder(_id);
        clearCurrent();
      };

      return (
        <div className='card bg-light'>
          <h3 className='text-primary text-left'>
            {_id}{' '}
            <span
              style={{ float: 'right' }}
              className={
                'badge ' +
                (productsellprice === 'professional' ? 'badge-success' : 'badge-primary')
              }
            >
              {'£ ' + productsellprice}
            </span>
          </h3>
          <ul className='list'>
            {useremail && (
              <li>
                <i className='fas fa-marker' /> {useremail}
              </li>
            )}
            {productname && (
              <li>
                <i className='fas fa-marker' /> {productname}
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>
          <p>
            <button
              className='btn btn-dark btn-sm'
              onClick={() => setCurrent(order)}
            >Edit
            </button>
            <button className='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onClick={onDelete}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </p>
        </div >
      );
    };

    OrderItem.propTypes = {
      order: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    export default OrderItem;
```

I want to display the order data in a simple ui card. Currently it only displays the order_id

Comment: `console.log(order)` and check what details it print, probably you are using wrong key names.

Comment: I got this:   Object
product: {_id: "5d1a62c40d16f11d94009a7a", name: "Lead18", sellprice: 104}
saledate: "2019-07-03T19:08:05.630Z"
user:
email: "irl1984@yahoo.co.uk"
name: "Kevin Kane"
_id: "5d1cd8fbc02bc928d83ea109"
__proto__: Object
_id: "5d1cfd156cd4673840981c5d"
__proto__: Object
OrderItem.js:6 
Object
product: {_id: "5d1a62c40d16f11d94009a7a", name: "Lead18", sellprice: 104}
saledate: "2019-07-03T18:43:14.409Z"
user: {_id: "5d1cd8fbc02bc928d83ea109", name: "Kevin Kane", email: "irl1984@yahoo.co.uk"}
_id: "5d1cf74207fa3337cceb5e1e"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Thank you @ravibagul91 perfect answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print `order` in console, you get this,

> Object product: {_id: "5d1a62c40d16f11d94009a7a", name: "Lead18", sellprice: 104} saledate: "2019-07-03T19:08:05.630Z" user: email: "irl1984@yahoo.co.uk" name: "Kevin Kane" _id: "5d1cd8fbc02bc928d83ea109" proto: Object _id: "5d1cfd156cd4673840981c5d" proto: Object OrderItem.js:6 Object product: {_id: "5d1a62c40d16f11d94009a7a", name: "Lead18", sellprice: 104} saledate: "2019-07-03T18:43:14.409Z" user: {_id: "5d1cd8fbc02bc928d83ea109", name: "Kevin Kane", email: "irl1984@yahoo.co.uk"} _id: "5d1cf74207fa3337cceb5e1e" proto: Object

It means you are getting object inside object.

So instead of this,

```
const { _id, username, useremail, productname, productsellprice } = order;
```

You should use [Destructuring nested objects](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8),

```
const { product:{_id: product_id}, user:{name: username}, user:{email: useremail}, product:{name: productname}, product:{sellprice: productsellprice} } = order;
```

Here I am not sure which `_id` you want to show, if you want `_id` from `user` object then use this `use:{_id}`.